# Facebook API - Batch upload photos

Tags: json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to batch upload photos and I keep getting a response back from Postman saying "Batch parameter must be a JSON Array"  Does anyone see what is wrong with this because it looks like valid json to me.  I've been rattling with this for a few hours making minor tweaks trying to get it to upload to no avail.  I also have tried encoding the url.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11?batch=[{"method":"POST", "relative_url":"https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/{pageid}/photos?access_token={access-token}", "body":"link_url":"https://{link-to-image}/wmphotos/999995/6d5cc4169bbf4e7dbe31f3739e025412/a572c29dff_640.jpg"}]&access_token={access-token}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, it seems that the JSON object in your `batch` array is actually malformed. `body:link_url:link` should be `body: {link_url:link}`

**Bad:**

```
[
    {
        "method":"POST", 
        "relative_url":"foo", 
        "body":"link_url":"link"
    }
]
```

**Good:**

```
[
    {
        "method":"POST", 
        "relative_url":"foo", 
        "body":{"link_url":"link"}
   }
]
```